# Passing infinite thread as a function

Tags: python, multithreading, flask

I have following Flask code:

```
def feed():
  return Response(inf_func(), mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')
```

This method is called every time someone enters a webpage. The problem with this is that it will put a heavy load on my Rasberry Pi and I would like to make it quicker by just running the "inf_func" (infinite function) once somewhere (so it's running all the time) and whenever this needs to be called, I just need to pass the ongoing function, not create a new one.

I tried passing a Thread, but Python says that "Thread object is not iterable".

Comment: What is `inf_func()`? What does it do?

Comment: inf_func() is a function that takes image using cv2 library every second. It's under "while True:" so it's infinite

Comment: Okay. You might want to instead have a thread do the capturing, save the image in a global variable there, then have inf_func read that global variable every second to stream to clients? :)

Comment: That's exactly what I am doing right now, although I have problems with jsonifying frame.